# Function for MySQLi statement doing nothing to database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following PHP code:

```
<?php
$email = 'email@email.com';
$phone = '+1 800 555 555';
//clean up phone number
$phone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $phone);

$plan = 'europe';
$ip = '99.55.44.44';
$sendEmails = True;

function addInfoToDatabase($token) {
        //function that adds data to temporary table. token is passed through

        //put new user info in database
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'php', '', 'php');

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `temp_users` VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '')");
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $email, $phone, $plan, $sendEmails, $token, $ip);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
addInfoToDatabase('24_tok');
?>
```

and it runs without returning an error. However, when I check my database, a row has not been added. My code looks correct, so why is this function doing nothing?

**Edit**: D'oh, I guess my problem lied in not passing the variables to the function. This works perfectly.

```
<?php
$email = 'email@email.com';
$phone = '+1 800 555 555';
//clean up phone number
$phone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $phone);

$plan = 'europe';
$ip = '99.55.44.44';
$sendEmails = True;

function addInfoToDatabase($email, $phone, $plan, $sendEmails, $token, $ip) {
        //function that adds data to temporary table. token is passed through

        //put new user info in database
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'php', '', 'php');

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `temp_users` VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '')");
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $email, $phone, $plan, $sendEmails, $token, $ip);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
addInfoToDatabase($email, $phone, $plan, $sendEmails, '24_tok', $ip);
?>
```

Comment: You may need to use double quotes instead of singles, due to the `+` sign in `$phone = '+1 800 555 555';` try replacing it with `$phone = "+1 800 555 555";` I'll bet it's trying to do a math equation. And also changing `$ip = '99.55.44.44';` to `$ip = "99.55.44.44";` try that out.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Just tried that. Same result as before. No data is in the database.

Comment: @Fred-ii- PHP doesn't try to do math in strings. The only difference between single and double quotes is with escape sequences and variable interpolation.

Comment: _it runs without returning an error_ -- you aren't checking for errors, so how do you know?

Comment: Ok, thanks @Barmar - I thought the quotes would have made a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the variables `$email`, `$phone`, `$plan`, `$sendEmails`, and `$ip` in your function, but they are set only outside the function. This means they are globals, so you can only access them if you pass them to your function as parameters.

The result of not doing so is that you are passing `null` values to your database. If any of the columns in question is defined with `NOT NULL` (and they probably are), then the query will fail.  You can verify the reason for the failure by running this code:

```
echo 'error '.$mysqli->errno().': '.$mysqli->error().'<br/>';
```

Comment: Fair enough; I agree it would be better. I was trying not to confuse OP, but will bow to peer pressure. Edited.

Comment: Or, put the variables inside the function itself, instead of using `global`? @EdCottrell